# Storybook hot reloading causes hooks error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, storybook

I get the following error when my storybook hot reloads. It works perfectly on the first load:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hooks' of undefined
at StoryStore.cleanHooks (http://localhost:9009/vendors~main.0e777466815571a0333e.bundle.js:6197:22)
at renderMain (http://localhost:9009/vendors~main.0e777466815571a0333e.bundle.js:8181:22)
at StoryStore.renderUI (http://localhost:9009/vendors~main.0e777466815571a0333e.bundle.js:8296:9)
at StoryStore.emit (http://localhost:9009/vendors~main.0e777466815571a0333e.bundle.js:6474:35)
at http://localhost:9009/vendors~main.0e777466815571a0333e.bundle.js:5943:16
```

I am using a redux provider, although I am not sure if it is related. It's code and the stories look like this regardless:

```
// provider.tsx
const Provider: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                {children}
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
)

export default Provider


// decorators.tsx
export const withProvider = (storyFn: any) => <Provider>
    {storyFn()}
</Provider>


// 2-TodoCard.stories.tsx
const complete = () => <TodoCard todo={completeTodo} />  // the TodoCard is just a React.FC
const incomplete = () => <TodoCard todo={incompleteTodo} />

storiesOf('TodoCard', module)
    .addDecorator(withProvider)
    .add('complete', complete)
    .add('incomplete', incomplete)
```

webpack.config.js (inside .storybook/ - normal app uses default create-react-app webpack):

```
module.exports = ({ config }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use: [
            {
                loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader'),
            },
            // Optional
            {
                loader: require.resolve('react-docgen-typescript-loader'),
            },
        ],
    });
    config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
    // config.entry = config.entry.filter(singleEntry => !singleEntry.includes('/webpack-hot-middleware/'));  // hot reloading causing a hooks bug
    return config;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error was stemming from me using two different formats of writing stories, when I should have been using one or the other.

To quote the user Hypnosphi,

> @wgpsutherland Looks like you're mixing Component Story Format and
>   storiesOf API in your stories:
>
> ```
> export default {
>     title: 'Button',
> };
>
> storiesOf('Button', module)
>     .add('gray', () => <Button color='gray' fluid size='large' type='submit'>Add</Button>)
>     .add('blue', () => <Button color='blue' fluid size='large' type='submit'>Add</Button>)
> ```
>
> You have to pick one. So it should be either
>
> ```
> export default {
>     title: 'Button',
> };
>
> export const gray = () => <Button color='gray' fluid size='large' type='submit'>Add</Button>
> export const blue = () => <Button color='blue' fluid size='large' type='submit'>Add</Button>
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> storiesOf('Button', module)
>     .add('gray', () => <Button color='gray' fluid size='large' type='submit'>Add</Button>)
>     .add('blue', () => <Button color='blue' fluid size='large' type='submit'>Add</Button>)
> ```

See the full issue on the github here: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/8306

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen when I edited my .storybook/config.js file and didn't restart the storybook server. Once I stopped it and restarted it, this error went away.